# is root@localhost the same as Unix root with GUID = 0 and ID = 0?

Tags: mysql, unix

Is a Mysql root user (root@localhost) the same as the computer root account (GUID = 0, ID = 0) ?

I mean, is it the root which is executing the script?

How can I know if the users are the same?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The MySQL root user is an account inside the database only. It is called root because it is the most privileged user on the database server, and has access to everything. The root user on Linux (or any other Unix) is a completely separate thing.

The maximum privilege that a MySQL user can have is equal to the privilege that the MySQL daemon runs at. On most modern package-based systems, a non-privileged `mysql` user will be automatically created on the system for this purpose, during the installation process.